# (De)serialize enum as string in Scala 3

Tags: scala, serialization, circe, scala-3

I am trying to find a simple and efficient way to (de)serialize enums in Scala 3 using `circe`.

Consider the following example:

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.syntax._

enum OrderType:
  case BUY
  case SELL

case class Order(id: Int, `type`: OrderType, amount: String)
val order = Order(1, OrderType.SELL, "123.4")
order.asJson
```

On serializing the data, it becomes

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "type" : {
    "SELL" : {
      
    }
  },
  "amount" : "123.4"
}
```

instead of

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "type" : "SELL",
  "amount" : "123.4"
}
```

which is what I want.

I know that I can write a custom (de)serializer for this which will solve the issue for this particular instance like this:

```
implicit val encodeOrderType: Encoder[OrderType] = (a: OrderType) =>
  Encoder.encodeString(a.toString)
  
implicit def decodeOrderType: Decoder[OrderType] = (c: HCursor) => for {
  v <- c.as[String]
} yield OrderType.valueOf(v)
```

but I was looking for a generic solution that might work for any `enum`.

**EDIT 1**

One way of doing serialization, (deserialization does not work :/) is to make all enums extend a common trait and define encoder for all enums extending it. For the above example, it looks something like this.

```
trait EnumSerialization

enum OrderType extends EnumSerialization:
  case BUY
  case SELL
  
enum MagicType extends EnumSerialization:
  case FIRE
  case WATER
  case EARTH
  case WIND

implicit def encodeOrderType[A <: EnumSerialization]: Encoder[A] = (a: A) => Encoder.encodeString(a.toString)

// This correctly serializes all instances of enum into a string
case class Order(id: Int, `type`: OrderType, amount: String)
val order     = Order(1, OrderType.SELL, "123.4")
val orderJson = order.asJson
// Serializes to { "id" : 1, "type" : "SELL", "amount" : "123.4"}

case class Magic(id: Int, magic: MagicType)
val magic = Magic(3, MagicType.WIND)
val magicJson = magic.asJson
// Serializes to { "id" : 3, "magic" : "WIND"}
```

However this does not extend to deserialization.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Scala 3 you can use Mirrors to do the derivation directly:

```
import io.circe._

import scala.compiletime.summonAll
import scala.deriving.Mirror

inline def stringEnumDecoder[T](using m: Mirror.SumOf[T]): Decoder[T] =
  val elemInstances = summonAll[Tuple.Map[m.MirroredElemTypes, ValueOf]]
    .productIterator.asInstanceOf[Iterator[ValueOf[T]]].map(_.value)
  val elemNames = summonAll[Tuple.Map[m.MirroredElemLabels, ValueOf]]
    .productIterator.asInstanceOf[Iterator[ValueOf[String]]].map(_.value)
  val mapping = (elemNames zip elemInstances).toMap
  Decoder[String].emap { name =>
    mapping.get(name).fold(Left(s"Name $name is invalid value"))(Right(_))
  }

inline def stringEnumEncoder[T](using m: Mirror.SumOf[T]): Encoder[T] =
  val elemInstances = summonAll[Tuple.Map[m.MirroredElemTypes, ValueOf]]
    .productIterator.asInstanceOf[Iterator[ValueOf[T]]].map(_.value)
  val elemNames = summonAll[Tuple.Map[m.MirroredElemLabels, ValueOf]]
    .productIterator.asInstanceOf[Iterator[ValueOf[String]]].map(_.value)
  val mapping = (elemInstances zip elemNames).toMap
  Encoder[String].contramap[T](mapping.apply)

enum OrderType:
  case BUY
  case SELL
object OrderType:
  given decoder: Decoder[OrderType] = stringEnumDecoder[OrderType]
  given encoder: Encoder[OrderType] = stringEnumEncoder[OrderType]
end OrderType
```

```
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.generic.auto._

case class Order(id: Int, `type`: OrderType, amount: String)
val order = Order(1, OrderType.SELL, "123.4")
order.asJson
// {
//   "id" : 1,
//   "type" : "SELL",
//   "amount" : "123.4"
// }: io.circe.Json
```

It uses `inline` and `Mirror` to

- get a list of types of sum type elements
- get a list of labels of these types
- obtain their values to create `Map[String, T]` or `Map[T, String]`
- `emap`/`contramap` `String` codecs so that translation wouldn't be nested nor require discriminating field

It only works with enums made of `case object`s and it would fail if any `case` stored some nested data - for that use standard derivation procedure with discriminator fields or nested structure named after the nested type.

You could import `stringEnumDecoder` and `stringEnumEncoder` and make them given, although I would prefer to add them manually, since they are more of an exception than a rule.

Answer (score 3):

Try constructing `Encoder` and `Decoder` instances via strings

```scala
  import io.circe.*
  import io.circe.parser.*
  import io.circe.syntax.*

  enum OrderType:
    case BUY
    case SELL

  given Encoder[OrderType] = (a: OrderType) => a.toString.asJson
  given Decoder[OrderType] = (c: HCursor) =>
    Decoder.decodeString(c).flatMap { str =>
      Try(OrderType.valueOf(str)).toEither.leftMap { _ =>
        DecodingFailure(s"no enum value matched for $str", List(CursorOp.Field(str)))
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a library that helps you with this: [circe-tagged-adt-codec-scala3](https://github.com/abdolence/circe-tagged-adt-codec-scala3)

With this your code looks like

```
import org.latestbit.circe.adt.codec._

enum OrderType derives JsonTaggedAdt.Encoder:
  case BUY
  case SELL
  
enum MagicType derives JsonTaggedAdt.Encoder:
  case FIRE
  case WATER
  case EARTH
  case WIND
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try that out!